# How can i retrieve the label from a Neo4j record using the Neo4j.Driver in C#

Tags: c#, neo4j

I am using the Neo4j.Driver in C# to query a Neo4J database. My cypher query returns multiple nodes that don't have the same label, lets say i return both movies and actors. I have a C# Movie and a C# Actor class. In order to instantiate the proper C# class (either movie or actor) and set the properties based on the returned records, how do i find out what label(s) a returned node has?

```
var cursor =  await transaction.RunAsync(cypher.ToString());
            await cursor.ForEachAsync(record =>
            {
                var movie = new Movie();
                movie.Name = record["name"].As<string>();
                ....
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

On a `Node` object you should find the `Labels` property, @see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-dotnet-driver/blob/7d954b4d86d134b360a8889ff14a2b6b1a339d7f/Neo4j.Driver/Neo4j.Driver/Types/INode.cs#L31

As an example :

```
var cursor =  await transaction.RunAsync(cypher.ToString());
await cursor.ForEachAsync(record =>
{
  var movie = new Movie();
  movieNode = record["movie"].As<INode>();
  movieNode.Labels[0]
  ....
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am not sure how to use your answer. The Node class is an internal type, so not exposed via the public API. What i get back from is a bunch of IRecord instances which is basically key/value (dictionary). Could you give some more pointers please?